# GSON deserialize Object by its field names

Tags: java, android, gson, deserialization

Lets assume we have this json:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "first_name": "name"
 "studentId": "1235234"
}
```

I know I can deserialize this with GSON by making Class like this:

```
class Student {
  int id;
  String first_name;
  String studentId;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same results by using two classes, ie.

```
class User {
   int id;
   String first_name;
}

class Student {
   User user;
   String studentId;
}
```

Is there a way to specify with some annotation to GSON so that it knows how populate 'user' object, except by Student class extending User class?

**UPDATE**:

1) Thanks for suggestion with extending, but I forgot to mention that I can't extend the 'User' (don't ask why :)), so thats why I'm looking for a workaround in a first place.

2) Custom deserializer would do the job, but I have multiple classes that have 'User' inside, so that would mean a lot of added classes and I also want to avoid that.

Thanks in advance,
Milos

Comment: you can use it with new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.toString, Student.class); and new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.toString, User.class);

Comment: if Student extends User , i think this will work using `Student.class` as param to `fromJson()`

Comment: You have to create custom deserializer for Student class in this case. But in addition to @Yazan's comment: it looks more logical if Student extends User, and not 'contains' User inside. Student is still a User, right?

Comment: Thanks for anwsers, updated the question....the problem appeared just because I should avoid extending the User class.
Re: custom deserializer - Can I 'customize' only this part and let other fields get deserialized automatically, or I need to write parsing code for whole class

Comment: You can use this site for generating Gson classes. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Answer (score 0):

Just change the structure of your Student class to

```
public class StudentData{
    private String studentId;
    private User user;

    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public class User {
        int id;
        String first_name;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirst_name() {
            return first_name;
        }

        public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, doesn't work cause JSON is like this:
{
 "id": 1,
 "first_name": "name"
 "studentId": "1235234"
}

Comment: Okay your JOSN structure is like this. Then you need to two different call to Gson().fromJson() once for the Student class and the other for the User class. But the User class inside the Student class will remain null.

Answer (score 0):

define a custom Deserializer:

```
public class StudentDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Student>{

@Override
public Student deserialize(JsonElement arg0, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2)
        throws JsonParseException {
    JSONObject jobject = (JsonObject) arg0;
    Student st = new Student();
    st.studentId = jobject.get("studentId").getAsString();
    st.user = new User();
    st.user.id = jobject.get("id").getAsInt();
    st.user.first_name = jobject.get("first_name").getAsString()
    return Student;
}
```

}

then register it before deserialization:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Student.class, new StudentDeserializer());
```

Comment: Hi, yep, that would work, though if I have 5-6 'Student' classes that would mean 5-6 Custom Deserializers would have to be written, and I would want to avoid that if possible.